# How can I add a second Twitter account to iOS Contacts/iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts, twitter

iOS 5 recently added Twitter and Facebook fields for contacts, and this was also incorporated into iCloud. However, it seems that you can only add one Twitter (and Facebook) account per contact, which is rather inconvenient as I know several people who have 2 Twitter accounts.

Is there a way to add a second Twitter field to iOS Contacts or iCloud? I know I could add a `twitter:@username` URL, but I was wondering if it's possible to natively add a second account.

Comment: Strangely I never though of adding multiple twitter ids through the iOS interface before I found your question. Now we know it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to assign multiple twitter ids to a contact. You have 2 ways of achieving this. Through iOS or through the Address Book app on Mac OS.

**On iOS 5** you can add multiple Twitter accounts to a contact on the device like this:

- Chose a contact
- Edit
- Add field ...
- Select Twitter
- Enter the twitter account

When you already have a Twitter account field you can't add another one like this anymore. Instead you will have to do as follow:

- Under the Twitter field you will see an empty field for Facebook, LinkedIn, Myspace or Flickr
- select this empty field's name and chose Twitter
- Enter the additional Twitter account

You can repeat this procedure for additional accounts.

This doesn't seem very intuitive at first, but it looks like Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, Myspace and Flickr are simply subcategories for a dedicated "social network" field and are managed just like other multiple entries fields on the device:

- email -> work, home...
- url -> home page, home, work, other...
- date -> anniversary, other

---

**On Mac OS** using the Address Book Application.
Select the contact you want to edit, edit it.

- To to the menu `Card -> Add Field -> Twitter` ...
- And add the twitter account.

Repeat as many times as needed.

Your contacts will sync shortly afterward.